# Распаковка словаря из колонки в dataframe на колонки и значения

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, словари

[image: Датасет с игроками и их наградами]

Как на python распаковать awards на колонку названия наград и в значение год сезон, когда была получена.

Примерная структура таблицы:

| player_name | russia2_silver_medal | mhl_allstar_game |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sergei Belov | 2009-2010 | NaN |
| Rafael Khakimov | NaN | 2010-2011 |

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('путь')["название столбца/ключ"]
```

Так вы из файла прочитает только нужный для вас столбец. Если нужно прочитать несколько, то вот

```
df = pd.read_csv('путь')[["название столбца/ключ", "название столбца/ключ"]]
```